# From worse to better

Tags: phrase-requests

I have a list of similar items (e.g., book titles), where some items are better/worse then others, and arranged from worse items (it the top of list) to better ones (in the bottom). This list should have a title - I think about "From worse to better" - but this phrase have suspiciously few mentions in Google. And it doesn't sound really good to me. Are there better  alternatives?

Comment: It sounds a hair odd, perhaps, but nothing wrong with it, and nothing wrong with having an "odd" title for something you write.

Comment: It's probably not mentioned (and possibly even sounds odd) because it's usual to go the other way: "from better to worse"; "from good to bad"; "from the sublime to the ridiculous"; "from the frying pan to the fire".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might sound better to say "from worst to best". Superlative forms are commonly used in descriptions of how lists are ranked.

Here are a few examples taken from Google search results: *Every Episode of Game of Thrones Ranked From Worst to Best; The Films of Hayao Miyazaki, Ranked from Worst to Best; Ranking Every Metallica Album from Worst to Best.*

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting because *from better to worse* is a very well known phrase—yet reversing it doesn't sound quite right.

To me, however, I would reverse it in a different fashion.

Instead of the original (and opposite) meaning:

> From better to worse.

Or the new (but awkward):

> From worse to better.

I would use:

> *To* better *from* worse.

That gives the meaning you're looking for while still preserving the natural flow of the same words that we're used to.

Comment: Actually, "from worse to better" is more common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+better+to+worse%2Cfrom+worse+to+better&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20better%20to%20worse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cfrom%20worse%20to%20better%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfrom%20worse%20to%20better%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFrom%20worse%20to%20better%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @HotLicks But, to me, it doesn't *sound* nearly as nice. And the question already stated that it didn't sound good—so it was rejected. Sometimes an answer can support something that was rejected in a question—but I don't think that works here.

Comment: Of course, a lot of "sounding nice" simply has to do with how the words "roll".  The trailing S sound in "worse" requires enough tongue gymnastics that it works better at the end of a phrase than in the middle.